# Is there an equivalent to TRY_CONVERT() in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

TRY_CONVERT() in T-SQL would return a value cast to the specified data type if the cast succeeded; otherwise it would return NULL.

Is there a similar function in ORACLE or a way to reproduce this behaviour?

Comment: I asked a similar question for PostgreSQL (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/203934/postgresql-alternative-to-sql-server-s-try-cast-function/311980#311980) and got a few good responses. If you’re up to writing a function, that would be a good long term solution. Hopefully by now you’re using a more current version of Oracle, so you can take advantage of @Radagast81’s answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not on Oracle 12.2 you can use a regex to determine if the value is valid before casting. For an integer (in the math sense, meaning optional sign, then one or more digits):

```
SELECT
  CASE WHEN REGEXP_LIKE(col, '^[-+]?[0-9]+$') THEN CAST(col AS NUMBER) END AS num
FROM myTable
```

This gives the same behavior as the Oracle 12.2 `DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR`.

For values other than integers the same approach applies, but the regexes get tougher.

Comment: Thanks this solved my problem except that I had to remove the '\' from the regular expression, otherwise I would get an error ORA-12728 -  "invalid range in regular expression"

Comment: Glad it helped, and thanks for letting me know about the backslash - I goofed up there. I've fixed the answer.

Answer (score 18):

You can use `cast(... DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR)` since version 12.2.

Complete Example:

```sql
SELECT cast('ABC' AS NUMBER DEFAULT NULL ON CONVERSION ERROR) FROM dual
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately this won't work for me since I'm using a 11.2 version of Oracle.

Comment: This is a nice feature, and more flexible that MSSQL’s `try_cast`.

Answer (score 0):

You cited Oracle PL/SQL so you might try an EXCEPTION block which could be contained in a user-defined function.  This will work with 11.2 version of Oracle.

```
DECLARE
    nTest       NUMBER;
BEGIN
    nTest := CAST ('ABC' AS NUMBER);
EXCEPTION WHEN VALUE_ERROR THEN
    nTest := NULL;
END;
```